# React sprite animation

Tags: reactjs, sprite

I want to create a small animation with sprites and want to find the most appropriate tool/library for that. Basically I'd like to know what is the equivalent to [keyframes](https://code.facebook.com/posts/354469174916519/keyframes-delivering-scalable-high-quality-animations-to-mobile-clients/) for react non-native.

I've tried creating gifs but the transparency has a lot of artifacts. I can use something like phaser/pixi.js but it seems a bit of overkill for something that is just a simple animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some simple ways:

Css animations (or the equivalent using js):

```
    {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background: url(https://cssanimation.rocks/images/posts/steps/heart.png) no-repeat;
      background-position: 0 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      animation: fave-heart 1s steps(28);
    }
    .heart:hover {
      background-position: -2800px 0;
      transition: background 1s steps(28);
    }
    @keyframes fave-heart {
      0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: -2800px 0;
      }
    }
```

http://codepen.io/mindstorm/pen/aZZvKq

React-spriteseet:
https://github.com/frostney/react-spritesheet